# Porqué la etiqueta <pubDate> se genera en el RSS como <pubdate>

Tags: php, rss

vengo con esta duda ya que no me había pasado jamás!

al validar el RSS con https://validator.w3.org/feed/ , me arroja un error incómodo como se ve en la siguiente imagen la etiqueta `<pubDate>` se me está abriendo como `<pubdate>` y genera el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando PHP 7.4 y este es mi codigo

```
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n"; ?>
<rss version="2.0"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
     xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
<channel>
    <title><?= $feedName; ?></title>
    <link><?= $feedUrl; ?></link>
    <description><?= convertToXmlCharacter(xml_convert($pageDescription)); ?></description>
    <dc:language><?= $pageLanguage; ?></dc:language>
    <dc:creator><?= $creatorEmail; ?></dc:creator>
    <dc:rights><?= convertToXmlCharacter(xml_convert($settings->copyright)); ?></dc:rights>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<item>
<title><?= convertToXmlCharacter(xml_convert($post->title)); ?></title>
<link><?= generatePostUrl($post); ?></link>
<guid><?= generatePostUrl($post); ?></guid>
<description><![CDATA[ <?= $post->summary; ?> ]]></description>
<?php
if (!empty($post->image_url)):
$imagePath = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $post->image_url ?? ''); ?>
<enclosure url="<?= $imagePath; ?>" length="49398" type="image/jpeg"/>
<?php else:
$imagePath = base_url($post->image_mid);
if (!empty($imagePath)) {
$fileSize = @filesize(FCPATH . $post->image_mid);
}
$imagePath = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $imagePath ?? '');
if (!empty($imagePath)):?>
<enclosure url="<?= $imagePath; ?>" length="<?= (isset($fileSize)) ? $fileSize : '12'; ?>" type="image/jpeg"/>
<?php endif;
endif; ?>
<pubDate><?= date('r', strtotime($post->created_at)); ?></pubDate>
<dc:creator><?= convertToXmlCharacter($post->username); ?></dc:creator>
</item>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Cómo puedes ver, en el PHP la estiquetá se abre y se cierra correctamente.

Ya intenté actualizando la versión de PHP, eliminado la caché del sitio wb, y nada parece funcionar.

Por otro lado si borro la línea  `<pubDate><?= date('r', strtotime($post->created_at)); ?></pubDate>` ya no hay errores en la validación pero el contenido no se actualizaría por que no tendría la fecha de refernecia para leer el contenido.

De antemano mil gracias a quien me de una guía sobre cómo solucionar este error..

Actualización:

Incluso he tratado escribiendo dos veces la misma línea de código `<pubDate><?= date('r', strtotime($post->created_at)); ?></pubDate>` y ambas salen igual la primera etiqueta todo en minúscula y la etiqueta de cierre si sale correctamente.

Comment: No hay un `endif;` duplicado? Tienes `if:`, `else:` y luego, dos `endif;` en líneas diferentes.

Comment: No, no está repetido.

Comment: De hecho he tratado de cambiar la ortografía, y no importa como escriba la etiqueta en el archivo php, sigue saliendo en minúsculas